# Partial pasting of subtotaled data

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to paste a subtotaled visible range to another sheet. Code being used by me is omitting last few rows. Could someone guide me to mistake in the code followed by me to enable me to paste the shaded last few rows in the image to Sheet2 as well.

[image: Sheet1 to be subtotaled][image: subtotaled sheet with omitted shaded lines][image: Sheet2 with partial pasted data]

Code followed by me is as follows

```
  Sub CopySubtotaledRange()
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim tgt As Worksheet
    Dim SubtotalRange As Range
    Dim copyRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set src = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set tgt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    ' find the last row with data in column A
    lastRow = src.Range("A" & src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' the range that we are Subtotaling (all columns)
    Set SubtotalRange = src.Range("A1:G" & lastRow)

    ' the range we want to copy
    Set copyRange = src.Range("A1:G" & lastRow)

    ' Subttotal range grouped on column B and totals based on column E and F
        SubtotalRange.Subtotal GroupBy:=2, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(5, 6), _
        Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2

    ' copy the visible cells to our target range
    copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy tgt.Range("A1")

End Sub
```

File tryme1.xlsm is [here](http://1drv.ms/1oFfIla)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code.  Your lastRow calc wasn't correct for the copyRange, since it counted before the subtotals were added.

```
Sub CopySubtotaledRange()
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim tgt As Worksheet
    Dim SubtotalRange As Range
    Dim copyRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set src = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set tgt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    ' find the last row with data in column A
    lastRow = src.Range("A" & src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' the range that we are Subtotaling (all columns)
    Set SubtotalRange = src.Range("A1:G" & lastRow)

    ' Subttotal range grouped on column B and totals based on column E and F
        SubtotalRange.Subtotal GroupBy:=2, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(5, 6), _
        Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2

    lastRow = Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row

    ' the range we want to copy
    Set copyRange = src.Range("A1:G" & lastRow)

    ' copy the visible cells to our target range
    copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy tgt.Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)